# Generalizing isNothing

Tags: haskell, error-handling, typeclass, option-type

So let's say we want to deal with computations that can fail using a container similar to Maybe.  If I were to specify a typeclass for what I want to do, it'd look something like this:

```
class Alternative f => Nullable f where
  isEmpty :: f a -> Bool
```

Such that `isEmpty x == True` if and only if `x = empty`

Is there some existing typeclass that I should use for this functionality or should I just use the class above?

EDIT: Some more context

I'm trying to implement matching for logic programming, and I want to be able to have a "not pattern" i.e. "succeed if and only if this program fails, then do ___".

Comment: Is `Either a` considered nullable?  A value of `Left "An error"` isn't really a null value conceptually, there's only a few types that this might be truly applied to if you're going for a conceptual notion of nullable.  You could look at the `Control.Monad.Trans.Error.Error` class which defines `noMsg :: Error a => a` and `strMsg :: Error a => String -> a`, it's pretty similar to what you want to do but adds messages instead of just a boolean flag for nullable.

Comment: `Either a` is nullable if for any type a that has a sensible default value.  The point of `Nullable` in my mind was more to generalize `Maybe` so that I could write code that normally would be within `Maybe` while abstracting away from that particular container.

Also, `Control.Monad...Error` doesn't really work, since I can't test to see if it's an error and handle it somehow.  I want to emulate something like `case x of (Just xs -> ...) (Nothing -> ...)`

Comment: [`Control.Monad.Error`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html) exports some structures to help handle failures. You can use `catchError` to wrap a block of statements which may call `throwError` and handle the error. I think this probably subsumes your `Nullable` use-case, though I don't have time to work out a full example.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you could use `Foldable` in this manner. `Maybe`, `[]`, `Either`, `ErrorT`, `ExceptT` are all `Foldable`. You can just pattern-match on the result of `toList`.

And in cases when you want to do something with the results of a successful execution and nothing in case of failure, you can use `forM_` directly.

Alternatively, you could use the [`MonoidNull`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-subclasses-0.4.0.4/docs/Data-Monoid-Null.html#t:MonoidNull) typeclass from [`monoid-subclasses`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-subclasses-0.4.0.4), that provides the `null` predicate.

Comment: Or use `foldMap` with `All` to define `null =  getAll . foldMap (const $ All False)`.

Comment: @PetrPudlák, why not just `null = Data.Foldable.all (const False)`? Or wait for base 4.8 :-)

Comment: @dfeuer True, even better :). Yes, in base-4.8 there will be [`null :: (Foldable t) => t a -> Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/candidate/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:null).

Answer (score 1):

As had been foretold in the comments to [danidiaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28779533/revisions), *base-4.8* generalised the type of `null`, making it an easy at reach emptiness test for `Foldable` containers:

```
GHCi> :t null
null :: Foldable t => t a -> Bool
GHCi> null Nothing
True
GHCi> null (Left "An error")
True
GHCi> null []
True
GHCi> import qualified Data.Map as Map
GHCi> null Data.Map.empty
True
```